# Ajax call to WCF returning error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I'm getting the error:

> *The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected
>   message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation
>   are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not
>   been configured on the binding. See the documentation of
>   WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more
>   details.*

I'm making the ajax call to the WCF Service like so:

```
function WCFJSON() {
var now = new Date();

var getFromDate = dateToWcf(new Date(now - (60000 * 1440)));

var userid = "1";
m_Type = "POST";
m_Url = "https://dev-04.boldgroup.int/ManitouDashboard/DashboardProxyService.svc/GetStats"
m_Data = "{'fromdate':'" + getFromDate + "'getvaluelist':'[1,2,3]'}";
m_DataType = "json";
m_ProcessData = true;             
CallService();
}

function dateToWcf(input) {
var d = new Date(input);
if (isNaN(d)) {
    throw new Error("input not date");
}
var date = '\\\/Date(' + d.getTime() + '-0000)\\\/';
return date;
}

function CallService() {
$.ajax({
    type: m_Type,           //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb                  
    url: m_Url,                 //Location of the service   
    data: m_Data,
    dataType: m_DataType,   //Expected data format from server                  
    processdata: m_ProcessData, //True or False
    crossdomain: true,    
    contentType: "application/json",             
    success: function (msg) {   //On Successfull service call                      
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ServiceFailed("jqXHT: " + jqXHR.result + "Text Status: " + textStatus + " Error Thrown: " + errorThrown );
    } // When Service call fails              
});
}
```

My Service contract is declared like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDashboardWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetStats", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Dictionary<int,List<StatValue>> GetStats(DateTime getFromDate, List<int> getValueList);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetStatTypes", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<StatType> GetStatTypes();
}
```

Am I doing something incorrect in the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There seems to be an error in your `m_Data`. There is no comma between two items
   (m_Data = "{'fromdate':'" + getFromDate + " **,** 'getvaluelist':'[1,2,3]'}";)
2. Match parameter names (`fromdate` -> `getFromDate`, `getvaluelist` -> `getValueList`)
3. Use ISO 8601 date time format (2012-08-15T00:00:00+02:00) (i always use [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) for date/time, it kicks ass)
4. Remove extra ticks just in case, and use `JSON.stringify`.

> ```
> m_Data = JSON.stringify({
>   getFromDate: "'" + getFromDate + "'",
>   getValueList: [1,2,3]
> });
> ```

Comment: I changed my m_Data varible to 

    m_Data = JSON.stringify({
      getFromDate: "'" + getFromDate + "'",
      getValueList: [1,2,3]
    });